# When contributing to spring-boot, how to run unit tests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

When contributing to spring-boot, I want to run a unit test, let's say for example `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointIdTests`.

So I forked and cloned the spring-boot repository, and tried `./gradlew test --tests org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointIdTests` and `./gradlew test --tests EndpointIdTests`, but for the longer command I got:

```
> Task :spring-boot-project:spring-boot:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':spring-boot-project:spring-boot:test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointIdTests](--tests filter)
```

(The shorter command's results were similar.)

Is there an easy way to do this from the command line, or do I need to understand how gradle works?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The secret is, the "test" subcommand needs to be run from the relevant spring-boot module directory, not from the project root.

So for example,

```
cd spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator
../../gradlew test --tests EndpointIdTests
```

or better, including "check" to run checkstyle:

```
cd spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator
../../gradlew check test --tests EndpointIdTests
```

This answer is based on Stéphane Nicoll's insight, provided [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24299#issuecomment-735921292).